# Sending and receiving UDP packets in the same class

Tags: java, udp

I know that this is poor practice, but would it be possible to do the following?

```
Send packet1 to UDP port 1
port 1 receives packet1 and sends it to port 2
port 2 receives packet2 and sends it to port 3
```

I don't see how i could set this up, as port 2 and port 3 would already have to be listening, waiting in a `while (true)` loop.

Answer (score 1):

> port 2 and port 3 would already have to be listening

Correct

> waiting in a while (true) loop.

Incorrect. You would have had to *create* the `DatagramSockets`, but you don't currently have to be *receiving* them when you send to their ports.

However it is certainly best to do so. There's nothing stopping you starting separate receiving threads for all three ports, is there?